# how to change button background in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to change button background by clicking the button. But, I don't want to change background using `click` event.

I have tried in WPF and achieved it using below code:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" 
            Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="3" 
                            BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers >
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" 
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" 
                                Value="2"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" 
                                Value="Bold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Button Content="All" 
        Height="20" 
        Width="50" 
        Margin="2" 
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve the same functionality in UWP?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to change button background by clicking the button. But, I don't want to change background using click event.

For your requirement, You could realize it via use [`XamlBehaviors`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/blob/b49d3ddb42d7f947fe0842d27a50ab4cd28450ef/samples/CS/XAMLBehaviorsSample/DataTriggerControl.xaml). For example:

```
<Button>
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                </Core:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </Core:ChangePropertyAction>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

It is open source model and host all behaviors code on GitHub will allow new features and fixes to be addressed more quickly.